# Reference request for combinatorial problem related to $\max$ relation

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, textbook-recommendation

Let $x_{i - j}\in\{1,2,\ldots, N\}$, where $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,N\}$ (is fixed) and $0\leq j\leq i$.

Based on such context, I am interested in an explicit formula for the numbers of configurations of $(x_{i},x_{i-1},\ldots,x_{0})$ which satisfy the following relation:
\begin{align*}
\max\{x_{i},x_{i-1} - 1, x_{i-2} - 2, \ldots, x_{0} - i\} = i
\end{align*}

I do not need a full answer (though I would be glad to have one).

I would like to know if anyone could give me some reference so that I could solve it by myself.

I am quite interested in a closed formula if possible.

Any suggestion such as books and articles are more than welcome.

Comment: The relation between $i$ and $N$ is unclear.

Comment: You can consider that $i$ is fixed between $1$ and $N$.

Answer (score 2):

I also don't have a reference, but I think one should be able to do this fairly explicitly as follows [it appears that Peter Taylor alludes to this strategy in their comment above]:

First, note that much easier than your original question is to count the number of tuples $(x_i,...,x_0)$ with
$$\max\{x_i,x_{i-1}-1,x_{i-2}-2,...,x_0-i\} \le i,$$ since a tuple has this property exactly when each $x_{i-j} \le j+i$. Since by assumption each $x_{i-j} \in \{1,...,N\}$, for each $j$ we have exactly $\min(i+j,N)$ choices for the value of $x_{i-j}$.
Thus we see that the number of such tuples is
$ \prod_{j=0}^i \min(i+j,N) $; in particular, if $2i \le N$, then
the number of such tuples is just $(i)(i+1)\cdots(2i-1)(2i) = \frac{(2i)!}{(i+1)!}$.

But note that we can exactly analogously compute that the
number of tuples $(x_i,...,x_0)$ with
$$ \max \{ x_i , x_{i-1} - 1,..., x_0 - i \} \le i - 1$$
is $\prod_{j=0}^i \min(i+j-1,N)$, which again is $(i-1)(i)\cdots(2i-1)$ if $2i-1 \le N$.

But the difference between these two quantities gives exactly
the number of tuples with
$$ \max \{ x_i , x_{i-1} - 1,..., x_0 - i \} = i,$$
which is what you were looking for. So, for instance if $2i \le N$, the quantity you're looking for is
$$ i(i+1)\cdots(2i) - (i-1)(i)\cdots(2i-1) 
= [(2i - (i-1))](i)(i+1)\cdots(2i-1) = (i+1) \frac{(2i-1)!}{(i-1)!}. $$

The more general lesson here is that the condition $\max(a bunch of junk)=c$ is often hard to get your hands on; but the condition $max(a bunch of junk) \le c$ is equivalent to $j \le c$ for each piece of junk $j$, which is often easier. Thus, its often fruitful to convert problems of the former type into problem of the latter type, just as we did here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a reference, but I can suggest an approach for you to solve it yourself.  The idea is to condition on the first argument that achieves the maximum.  I'll illustrate it for the case $N=5$ and $i=3$.  The four cases are

\begin{align}
x_3 &= 3,& x_2 &\le 4,& x_1 &\le 5,& x_0 &\le 6 \\
x_3 &< 3,& x_2 &= 4,& x_1 &\le 5,& x_0 &\le 6 \\
x_3 &< 3,& x_2 &< 4,& x_1 &= 5,& x_0 &\le 6 \\
x_3 &< 3,& x_2 &< 4,& x_1 &< 5,& x_0 &= 6 \\
\end{align}

This approach yields
$$1\cdot 4\cdot 5 \cdot 6 + 2\cdot 1 \cdot 5 \cdot 6 + 2\cdot 3 \cdot 1\cdot 6 + 2\cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 1 = 240$$
configurations.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I forgot to mention I am looking for a closed formula.

Comment: Yes, this example was just to illustrate the idea.

Comment: Surely easier to count solutions to $\max\{x_{i},x_{i-1} - 1, x_{i-2} - 2, \ldots, x_{0} - i\} \le i$ and then subtract the number of solutions to $\max\{x_{i},x_{i-1} - 1, x_{i-2} - 2, \ldots, x_{0} - i\} < i$